# c# filter database results using EF similar to SQL WHERE Clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've connected to my database using Entity Framework and am building my first MVC app for use in a web page.

I can get the controller to populate public strings in my models with no problem... the issue I'm having is that I can't figure out how to filter responses from my database.

I expect to have only one item returned which I will display in the view with `@Model.BusinessUnit`

Here's my Model Class for the database table:

```
public partial class TBL_Wholesale_UWS_BusinessUnits
{
    public int PrimaryID { get; set; }
    public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Here's what I have in my controller:

```
public ActionResult test(int PrimaryID)
{
    var testing = new TBL_Wholesale_UWS_BusinessUnits();
    // maybe putting new is the wrong thing to do as that would be wiping the class? IDK
    return View(testing);
}
```

As you can see, the PrimaryID is passed to the controller via the querystring and this is recognised without issue, but I'm at a loss as to where to add the filter, I assumed it would be something like...

```
var testing = TBL_Wholesale_UWS_BusinessUnits.Where(TBL_Wholesale_UWS_BusinessUnits.PrimaryID = PrimaryID);`
```

but Visual Studio is telling me in no uncertain terms that this this wrong.

Had this been classic asp I would have just made a record set and used the where clause in SQL, but as this is built with the Entity Framework to do my connecting I don't really know where to start.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should start with an Entity Framework tutorial, not try arbitrary code. `TBL_Wholesale_UWS_BusinessUnits` is your entity, ie the result of the query. IT's *not* the DbContext object that connects to the database and allows you to execute queries.

Comment: var somethinngFilter = testing.Table.Where(x=>x.Field == PrimaryID).Tolist(); Assuming testing was your DbContext

Comment: @Seabizkit `testing` is the entity, not the DbContext. It's just a single empty class

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos got that after reading urs... yeah elboffor need to follow a simple EF tutorial

Comment: You really should do a couple of readings before start coding. Please, start learning about mvc basic patterns. Then you should learn more about EF and how to implement common patterns like repositories so you can consume that from your service layer. The `testing`class is just a class, not the dbcontext. Is not that I don't want to answer your question, but I see that you really need to do a deep dive on these subjects...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only trying to return that **one** specific object to the view.. then you need to find that `int PrimaryID` in the database and retrieve that specific record.

What you are doing is simply creating a new instance of the `TBL_Wholesale_UWS_BusinessUnits` class which is *empty*.

Try this:

```
public ActionResult test(int PrimaryID)
{
    var testing = db.TableName.Find(PrimaryID);

    // db = Whatever the variable holding your connection string is.. maybe DbContext

    // TableName = Whatever table in your database that holds the record you want

    // This will return the specific object that you are looking for

    return View(testing);
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I would consider reformatting the `var testing...` line, might look confusing to a beginner.